# Preview fullscreen starts at two pages but reverts to continuous scroll

Tags: pdf, preview, fullscreen

When I open a pdf file in Preview and click full screen, Preview defaults to the "Two Pages" view option, which I prefer. However, every time I come back after being away from the computer, the Preview fullscreen windows have reverted back to the "Continuous View" option. Even though I can press Command+3 to return to Two Pages view, this is still very annoying. Is there any way to fix this?

I use a Mac Studio 2022 with macOS Monterey.

Comment: There was a Terminal command that used to work for this (`defaults write com.apple.Preview kPVPDFDefaultPageViewModeOption 2`) but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Preview will retain the view if I save the PDF after setting the view I want. eg:

1. open PDF
2. switch to 2 page view
3. save PDF
4. try coming back to it later/close the PDF and reopen. It *should* be in 2 page view automatically.

Comment: Didn't work for me :'(, saving the pdf doesn't do anything, if I then unplug the monitor and connect it, the pdf is in continuous scroll again